# How do I pass a ViewModel boolean to a jquery function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'd like a div to show if a ViewModel bool is set to true.

I tried this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#myDiv").toggle(@Model.IsRequired);
}
```

But `@Model.IsRequired` appears as either "True" or "False", rather than "true" or "false".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just write `@Model.IsRequired.ToString().ToLower()`.

I don't think there's any better solution (other than your own extension method)

Answer (score 3):

Some alternatives to just lowercasing the string:

Use the ternary operator with actual strings

```
$(function () {
    $("#myDiv").toggle(@(Model.IsRequired?"true":"false"));
}
```

or you can output different invocations depending on the value

```
$(function () {
    @if (Model.Required)
    {
        $("#myDiv").toggle(true);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#myDiv").toggle(false);
    }
}
```

or combine them

```
$(function () {
    @(Model.IsRequired
         ?"$('#myDiv').toggle(true);"
         :"$('#myDiv').toggle(false);")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's yet another way using jQuery / javascript:**

***Markup:***

```
<... onclick='HandleClick()' ... />
```

***Script:***

```
function HandleClick() {
    var isRequired = '@Model.IsRequired';
    if (isRequired === 'True') {
        $('#myDiv').toggle(true);
    } else {
        $('#myDiv').toggle(false);
    }
}
```